# Web Api Not recognizing RestClient framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to do a test post to a 3rd party web api.
The code how to post was provided by the documentation from 3rd party.

```
'RestClient' is a namespace but is used like a type
The type or namespace name 'RestRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'IRestResponse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The name 'ParameterType' does not exist in the current context
The name 'Method' does not exist in the current context
```

The method I am working with:

```
public void CreatePanelists (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data)
{

    Parameters parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parameters>(data.ToString())
    IList<Panelist> panelistList = parameters.panelists;
    string id = parameters.id;

    var client = new RestClient("https://3rdparty.com/v2/events/5893/atendees");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer vJRMZ92lsOE1sKGVF7_4zCezTjxO2RoFeOVGULSJS2_dRhgU5QfZeKqGaoS0ogPv0WISEuZ1RcNzJDUsv27uGA");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"attendees\":[{\"name\":\"Mary\",\"email\":\"maryjkdfdsgfshdgf@jdfdkjdglfk.jkfgdj\"},{\"name\":\"Mike\",\"email\":\"dfdsgfsdhf@jkgfdgfkdhgfdjg.fkjgdf\"}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}
```

I installed RestClient 4.0.0 but that did not remove the errors.

I am not using .Net not .net Core. What am I missing?

First time developing this type of project, please pardon if my technical language is not correct.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you,
Erasmo

UPDATE - I was able to install RestSharp Version 106.11.4.0, and RestClient Version 2.5.0.6.

The only error that persists is

```
'RestClient' is a namespace but is used like a type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you missed to include namespace for the use of RestClient package. use the following namespace at top of the file.

```
using RestSharp;
```

Also, you should install nuget package before use this RestClient package. If not installed , then use follow command in Nuget package manager console.

```
PM> install-package RestSharp
```

Comment: I am unable to install RestSharp. I updated my question with the reason.

Comment: You are able to installed Restsharp ? In question description you mentioned that "I installed RestClient 4.0.0 but that did not remove the errors."

Comment: I updated my question. RestSharp and RestClient are installed. The only error that parsists: 'RestClient' is a namespace but is used like a type

Answer (score 1):

The RestSharp code you're using is out of date for .Net Full Framework < 5.0.

The new RestSharp syntax looks like this: https://restsharp.dev/intro.html#basic-usage

```
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

var client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com/1.1");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");

var request = new RestRequest("statuses/home_timeline.json", DataFormat.Json);

var timeline = await client.GetAsync<HomeTimeline>(request, cancellationToken);
```

<sub>I've raised a support request #98090 to PostMan to update the RestSharp Code Generated.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

First you need to uninstall the `RestClient` packages :

> Manage  -> nuget packages

Then install `Restsharp` package.

> PM -> install-package RestSharp

then use using `RestSharp`

Answer (score 0):

Using RestSharp.RestClient would resolve the error. You would not need RestClient package.